# how to count different keys and related different values in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to count the number of absenties and number of presenties per section in below example.but it is not easy to me how count number of absenties and presenties per section can u help me any one....thanks in advance

```
<?php
Array(
    [0] => Array([Section] => Attendance) 
    [1] => Array([CSE - A] => PRESENT) 
    [2] => Array([CSE - G] => ABSENT) 
    [3] => Array([CSE - A] => ABSENT) 
    [4] => Array([CSE - C] => PRESENT) 
    [5] => Array([CSE - C] => PRESENT) 
    [6] => Array([CSE - C] => PRESENT) 
    [7] => Array([CSE - C] => PRESENT) 
    [8] => Array([IT] => PRESENT) 
    [9] => Array([CSE - D] => ABSENT) 
    [10] => Array([CSE - G] => ABSENT) 
    [11] => Array([CSE - B] => PRESENT) 
    [12] => Array([CSE - A] => ABSENT) 
    [13] => Array([CSE - C] => PRESENT) 
    [14] => Array([CSE - E] => ABSENT) 
    [15] => Array([CSE - B] => ABSENT) 
    [16] => Array([CSE - E] => ABSENT) 
    [17] => Array([CSE - F] => ABSENT) 
    [18] => Array([CSE - G] => ABSENT) 
    [19] => Array([CSE - G] => PRESENT) 
    [20] => Array([CSE - A] => ABSENT) 
    [21] => Array([CSE - D] => PRESENT) 
)
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Basically you have to write some code.

Comment: sorry man set `open` bound of your question.some one may have solution.

Answer (score 0):

`$table` is your data. You have to loop over each element. Then for each new key, you create data in a `$result` array initialized with `0` value. If the value is present, you add `1`.

```php
//Result initialization
$result = [];
//Loop over each element
foreach($table as $ligne){
    //foreach each element I catch key and its value
    foreach ($ligne as $key => $value){
        //initialization to zero if necessary              
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $result)) $result[$key] = 0;
        if ($value == 'PRESENT'){
            //If present I add 1
            $result[$key] += 1;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Here an example result with the first value of your array:

```php
array (size=2)
  'CSE - A' => int 1
  'CSE - G' => int 0
```

Repeat task with absent in an other array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.Here `$students` is a sample array exactly like as your posted array.

```
    <?php
$present = 0;
$absent = 0;
$students = array(array('CSE-A'=>'PRESENT'),array('CSE-G'=>'ABSENT'),array('CSE-G'=>'ABSENT'));//Sampled Array
foreach($students as $key=>$array)
{
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($array[$k] === 'PRESENT')
        {
            $present++;
        }
         else if ($array[$k] === 'ABSENT')
        {
            $absent++;
        }
    }
}
echo "Present Totals: ".$present.PHP_EOL;
echo "Absent Totals: ".$absent;
```

Output:

```
Present Totals: 1
Absent Totals: 2
```

Comment: i want ans like CSE-A  PRESENT-1

Comment: AND CSE-G ABSENT 2

Comment: you can take reference from this example...need to count every absents and presents on based on key.

Comment: i want output branch wise absenties and presenties

Comment: i tried whatever you said but am not getting correct output

Comment: can u provide out put for ur example like this:CSE-A-PRESENT:1 , ABSENT: 0 and CSE-G- PRESENT:0;ABSENT:2

Comment: I DONT WANT TOTAL NUMBER OF ABSENTIES AND PRESENTIES

Comment: I WANT BRANCH WISE ABSENTIES AND BRANCH WISE PRESENTIES

Comment: CAN YOU PROVIDE OUTPUT LIKE CSE-A :  PRESENT-4  ; ABSENT:5

Comment: CSE-B :  PRESENT-2  ; ABSENT:5

Answer (score 0):

**The solution** would be like this:

Create a multidimensional `$sectionRecords` array comprising of all the sections and the corresponding number of `PRESENT`s and `ABSENT`s, like this:

```
$sectionRecords = array(
    'CSE-A' => array(
        'PRESENT' => 0,
        'ABSENT' => 0
    ),
    'CSE-B' => array(
        'PRESENT' => 0,
        'ABSENT' => 0
    ),

    ...

    'IT' => array(
        'PRESENT' => 0,
        'ABSENT' => 0
    ),
);
```

Now loop through the original array to populate above array with the number of `PRESENT`s and `ABSENT`s for each section, like this:

(Suppose `$yourArray` is your original array)

```
foreach($yourArray as $arr){
    foreach($arr as $section => $status){
        if(array_key_exists($section, $sectionRecords)){
            ++$sectionRecords[$section][$status];
        }
    }
}
```

Later, you display the sections and the corresponding number of `PRESENT`s and `ABSENT`s like this:

```
foreach($sectionRecords as $section => $statArray){
    foreach($statArray as $status => $count){
        echo $section . ' ' . $status . ' ' . $count . '<br />';
    }
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** If you want to see the complete `$sectionRecords` array structure, do `var_dump($sectionRecords);`

Comment: I DONT WANT OUT LIKE U EXPECTED

Comment: I WANT OUT NUMBER OF PRESENTIES AND ABSENTIES PER SECTION

Comment: OUTPUT LIKE THIS:  CSE-A   PRESENTIES:5  ABSENTIES:2

Comment: CSE- B: PREENTIES: 6  ABSENTIES:2

Comment: CAN U PROVIDE CODE FOR THIS

Comment: @user7399549 The above code works exactly as you had expected it to work. See the demo code and output here, [http://pastebin.com/LB4xC1bt](http://pastebin.com/LB4xC1bt). Also, please don't post multiple comments, that too in caps. If possible, use a one(or two) comments to describe your problem.